# Replace Text and Link Target on a page

Tags: userscripts

I want to make a userscript that changes the Gmail link on Google.com to the Inbox one.

```
<a class="gb_la" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&amp;authuser=0" data-pid="23" data-ved="0CBEQwi4oAA">Gmail</a>
```

to:

```
<a class="gb_la" href="https://inbox.google.com/" data-pid="23" data-ved="0CBEQwi4oAA">Inbox</a>
```

But I know nothing about Javascript and/or userscripts. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

`<a class="gb_la" href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm&amp;authuser=0" data-pid="23" data-ved="0CBEQwi4oAA" id="link">Gmail</a>`

JavaScript:
`link=document.getElementById("link");
link.src="https://inbox.google.com/";
link.innerHTML="Inbox";`

Comment: this is standalone JavaScript and it's to be executed after the links have loaded

Comment: As I said I don't know anything about how such things work. Could you explain it a little further ?